# Buddypress: Language not changing

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I'm getting crazy because everything seems to be fine, but impossible to get a solution.

I want to translate my buddypress to Spanish.

Seems like I have everything ok:

My language files:

[image: languiage files]

My wp-config

define('WPLANG', 'es_ES');

My config on dashboard: **Setted to Spanish**

My wordpress version : 4.1.

My wordpress is translated ok once I set the language on the dashboard, anyway the **buddypress language does not change**.

Any Idea about what could be wrong here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create and upload the `buddypress-es_ES.mo` file. The `.po` files are used to create the `.mo` file. You don't need to upload the `.po` files.

Comment: Thanks, that was the answer.